# Mesh to Rig Not Working Correctly

Tags: rigging

I imported an animated rig from a kinect motion software program to blender.

When I connect my mesh to the armature "with automatic weights" and play it the character is twisted around and not right. vertex groups were not assigned right so I manually assigned them but where bones bend they are not right.

Tried disconnecting the bones and reconnecting them but still did not work. What would be the correct way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: hello, it's hard to say, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

Automatic weights doesn't always work well. The more complex the mesh, the higher the probability of issues with automatic weights.
Also, if your mesh's normals are not right it can make the automatic weighting a little wonky, so you can try recalculating normals before parenting to the armature (select the mesh, go into edit mode, hit 'A' to select all faces and then 'alt + n' and 'recalculate outside'. Hope it helps.

Comment: I recalculated the normals. They all were the right way and it still did not work. I see that weight painting with "with empty weights" is an option. I tried doing it but it seems like its going to come out the same way as manually assigning vertex groups. Is there a way so it automatically paints the body to match the bones?

Comment: That's what the 'parent with automatic weights' should do. It's not perfect but it should be roughly right and then you need to tweak it to get to a good result. I don't know why it isn't working in your case, sorry. Maybe with some screenshots (or even better, a screen capture video) it would be easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: got it to work. i used limited dissolve to lessen the vertex count which ended up messing the automatic weights up so i went back to how it was before. thank you for helping and also to moonboots earlier in the thread.